# Does Ubuntu Touch have a terminal and/or a compiler?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiler

Does Ubuntu Tablet have any sort of compiler where Python/C/C++ can be written and run?

Also, does it have a terminal?

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu Touch Terminal has already been released as an Ubuntu Touch Core App. For more information about the Ubuntu Touch Terminal visit the [Ubuntu Touch Terminal wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps/Terminal).